# Set event handler as parameter

Tags: c#, events

I need to doing something like this:

```
if ((sender as TextBox).Equals(TextBox1))
{
    TextBox2.TextChanged -= TextBox2_TextChanged;
    TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text;
    TextBox2.TextChanged -= TextBox2_TextChanged;
}
else if ((sender as TextBox).Equals(TextBox3))
{
    TextBox4.TextChanged -= TextBox4_TextChanged;
    TextBox4.Text = TextBox3.Text;
    TextBox4.TextChanged -= TextBox4_TextChanged;
}
```

But I have too many TextBoxes for if-else statement, so I would like to make something like this:

```
public void My_function(TextBox textbox1, TextBox textbox2, string event_name)
{
    textbox2.TextChanged -= event_name;
    textbox2.Text = textbox1.Text;
    textbox2.TextChanged -= event_name;
}
```

How can I doing this??? And can I do this at all???

Comment: If you pay attention to compile error, it will say `Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.EventHandler'`, so you can notice, that if you change your `string` to `EventHandler` it  should work.

Comment: @SeM, I'm understand this.My question was HOW can I doing it.

Comment: Instead of `string` write `System.EventHandler`?

Comment: @SeM, I'm understand that if I use string type, I will have a compile error. My question was how can I send event as function parameter. Anyway, I already received a response.

Comment: I'm repeating myself third time already, if you change the word `string` to `System.EventHandler` in your method, it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `EventHandler` [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventhandler(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
 private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      textBox1.Text = "hello";
 }

 public static void My_function(TextBox textbox1, EventHandler handler)
 {
    textbox1.TextChanged -= handler;
 }
```

and to call the function simply do

```
My_function(textBox1, textBox1_TextChanged);
```

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I needed.